# Import/Send Gmail and Work Email to iCloud Online?

Tags: icloud, email, gmail

SO I am a brand new Apple user. I have multiple email IDs, namely:

1. gmail.com
2. my office email

I want to import my old and new emails (both office and gmail) to iCloud online. I plan to delete my gmail after that and I want to send my office emails from iCloud (preferably web interface) (as in myname@myoffice.com and not @iCloud.com).

My concern is I have way too much mail to clutter my Mac and I would just be happy to store the mails online and have access to them through the iCloud online mail interface (that is ultimately making iCloud my onestop goto for all my emails).

Is that possible? If not what are my options?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's possible! The Mail app is great for keeping track of more than one email account and also has rule features, so if you're worried about clutter, you can set them to automatically get deleted. macOS also automatically clears space (if you allow it, Apple Logo up the top -> About This Mac -> Storage) after time.